# PowerApps gallery item checkbox when selecting dropdown based on status and patch to list item

Tags: powerapps-canvas

1)when nothing got checked in the gallery items but then I click final update button then items are getting patched randomly .

2. Need help on how to patch multiple selected items for the below gallery items

New update is :This is working fine but unless user enter input then it should not patch

Recent code
Set(varrecord,Gallery2.Selected);
ForAll(
Filter(
Gallery2.AllItems,
Checkbox1.Value
),
Patch(
Roster,
Defaults(Roster),
{

```
       Title:varrecord.Title,                   
       VacancyID: Value(TextInput1.Text),
       Division :varrecord.Division,
       Department:varrecord.Department,
       SRStatus:varrecord.SRStatus
      
                            
  
}
```

);
);
UpdateContext({locResetCheckbox:true});
Reset(TextInput1);
UpdateContext({locResetCheckbox:false});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your FinalUpdate button's OnSelect formula should be something more like this:

```
//For all items in your gallery that are checked
ForAll(
    Filter(
        Gallery_ShortSRdet.AllItems,
        Checkbox1.Value //Update with the name of your checkbox control
    ),
// Patch the Role field of your data source with the value of your dropdown control
    Patch(
        ShortlistedRoster,
        ThisRecord,
        {Role: Dropdown5.Selected.Value}
    )
);
```

**UPDATE**

To reset the checkboxes, add this to the end of the formula above:

```
UpdateContext({locResetCheckbox:true});
UpdateContext({locResetCheckbox:false})
```

you will then need to change the `Reset` property of your checkbox to `locResetCheckbox`

Comment: Thanks,how to clear the checkbox after selection.please help

Comment: I've updated my answer with instructions on how to reset the checkbox

Comment: Thanks a lot.Great help and it worked

Comment: Can you please help me with one more level of issues as when i click copy button then it should not patch unless my text box value is inputted and how to check that condition in my patching code

Comment: Please refer above code and it works fine when click copy button byt issue is textbox is required so how to check if textbox is not empty then patch